# Why won't values between 100 and 1000 work when playing Four is Magic, excluding values by 100

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation

Everything works besides values between 100 and 999, except values divisible by 100 work.

The game is as follows:

Four is magic. Write a Python program (called q3.py) that given an integer from 0 to 1000 does the “4 is magic” transformation. The steps are as follows:

1. Convert the integer n into English and count the number of letters (i.e. 21 is “twenty one” and consists of 9 letters, 102 is “one hundred two” and consists of 13 letters, 1000 is “one thousand” and consists of 11 letters).
2. Let `nlen` be the length of the English word equivalent for the integer n.

   a. If `nlen` is 4, output “four is magic.” Then, terminate the transformation process.

   b. Otherwise output “ is `nlen`.” Repeat
   step (a), where the integer n is set to `nlen`.

Suppose the user inputs the integer 26. Then, the transformation proceeds as follows.

1. 26 is 9. , where twenty six is the 9-letter English word equivalent of 26.
2. 9 is 4. , where nine is the 4-letter English word equivalent of 9.
3. 4 is magic.

```
def convert(number_str):

    # Enter your code here.
    count = 0
    index = 0
    x = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen']
    y = ['zero','ten','twenty','thirty','forty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']

    while (number_str != '4'):
        if 0 <= int(number_str) <= 19:
            a = len(x[int(number_str)])
            print(x[int(number_str)],'is',a)
            number_str = str(a)
        elif 20 <= int(number_str) <= 99:
            if number_str[1] == "0":
                a = len(y[int(number_str[0])])
                print(y[int(number_str[0])],'is',a)
                number_str = str(a)
            else:
                a = len(y[int(number_str[0])]) + len(x[int(number_str[1])])
                print(y[int(number_str[0])] + ' ' + x[int(number_str[1])],'is',a)
                number_str = a
        elif 100 <= int(number_str) <= 999:
            rem = int(number_str) % 100
            div = int(number_str) // 100
            if rem == 0:
                a = len(x[div]) + 7
                print(x[div] + ' hundred is',a)
                number_str = str(a)
            else:
                if (number_str[1] == '0'):
                    a = len(x[div]) + 7 + len(convert(str(rem)))
                    print(x[div] + ' hundred ' + convert(str(rem)) + ' is '+ str(a))
                    number_str = str(a)
                elif (number_str[1] != '0'):
                    a = len(x[div]) + 6 + len(convert(str(rem)))
                    print(x[div] + ' hundred ' + convert(str(rem)) + ' is '+ str(a))
                    number_str = str(a)
        elif number_str == '1000':
            a = 11
            print('one thousand is '+ str(a))
            number_str = str(a)
    return 'four is magic'

def main():
    ''' The program driver. '''

    user_input = input('> ')
    while  user_input != 'quit':
        print(convert(user_input))
        user_input = input('> ')


main()
```

My question is what is wrong with this area:

```
else:
            if (number_str[1] == '0'):
                a = len(x[div]) + 7 + len(convert(str(rem)))
                print(x[div] + ' hundred ' + convert(str(rem)) + ' is '+ str(a))
                number_str = str(a)
            elif (number_str[1] != '0'):
                a = len(x[div]) + 6 + len(convert(str(rem)))
                print(x[div] + ' hundred ' + convert(str(rem)) + ' is '+ str(a))
                number_str = str(a)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What is wrong with this area             else:
                if (number_str[1] == '0'):
                    a = len(x[div]) + 7 + len(convert(str(rem)))
                    print(x[div] + ' hundred ' + convert(str(rem)) + ' is '+ str(a))
                    number_str = str(a)
                elif (number_str[1] != '0'):
                    a = len(x[div]) + 6 + len(convert(str(rem)))
                    print(x[div] + ' hundred ' + convert(str(rem)) + ' is '+ str(a))
                    number_str = str(a)

Comment: @ReidJordan: It is difficult to understand what you want to get, and what you get instead.

Answer (score 0):

`convert` always returns `"four is magic"`  It looks like you want it to return some value based on its input.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(number_str):

    # Enter your code here.
    count = 0
    index = 0
    x = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen']
    y = ['zero','ten','twenty','thirty','forty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']

    while (number_str != '4'):
        if 0 <= int(number_str) <= 19:
            a = len(x[int(number_str)])
            print(x[int(number_str)],'is',a)
            number_str = str(a)
        elif 20 <= int(number_str) <= 99:
            if number_str[1] == "0":
                a = len(y[int(number_str[0])])
                print(y[int(number_str[0])],'is',a)
                number_str = str(a)
            else:
                a = len(y[int(number_str[0])]) + len(x[int(number_str[1])])
                print(y[int(number_str[0])] + ' ' + x[int(number_str[1])],'is',a)
                number_str = a
        elif 100 <= int(number_str) <= 999:
            rem = int(number_str) % 100
            div = int(number_str) // 100 
            print(div)
            if rem == 0:
                a = len(x[div]) + 7
                print(x[div] + ' hundred is',a)
                number_str = str(a)
            else:
                if (number_str[1] == '0'):
                    a = len(x[div]) + 7 + len(str(x[rem]))
                    print(x[div] + ' hundred ' + str(x[rem]) + ' is '+ str(a)) # error was here
                    number_str = str(a)
                elif (number_str[1] != '0'):
                    a = len(x[div]) + 6 + len(str(x[rem]))
                    print(x[div] + ' hundred ' + str(x[rem]) + ' is '+ str(a)) # error was here
                    number_str = str(a)
        elif number_str == '1000':
            a = 11
            print('one thousand is '+ str(a))
            number_str = str(a)
    return 'four is magic'


def main():
    ''' The program driver. '''

    user_input = input('> ')
    while  user_input != 'quit':
        print(convert(user_input))
        user_input = input('> ')


main()
```

Where I commented `#error` you were doing recursion which was not what you wanted ( I think). But fixed it and it should work now. When you call recursive functions (calling the same function) it execute the newest call on the stack, returning the value it came back with, which isn't how your program worked.

Also I noticed you weren't calling `x[rem]` like you were suppose to for a look up on the spelling, fixed that too.

Next time please include desired output instead of making us fish for information.